# How to get text from found component?

Tags: delphi

I have a problem with Text inside of a found `TEdit`.

This is my code:

```pascal
function TfrmGenerateExam.zlicz_liczby(Component: TControl): integer;
var
  i, j: integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  for i := 0 to Component.ComponentCount - 1 do
  begin
    for j := 0 to Panel.ComponentCount - 1 do
    begin
      if Components[j] is TEdit then
      begin
       Result := Result +  ???;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

In a nutshell:

I create dynamic panels with ComboBoxes, Edits, Buttons etc.

When I have some panels, I want to count the edits which are in panels, which are in ScrollBox:

[image: Preview]

What do I need to put here?

```pascal
if Components[j] is TEdit then
begin
  Result := Result +  ???;
end;
```

Comment: `StrToInt( (Components[j] as TEdit).Text )` as per interpreting your picture.

Comment: @AmigoJack  unfortunately its doesnt work : '' is not a valid integer value. - but value is not empty.

Comment: What is "Panel" in the second for ?

Comment: @MundoPeter its TPanel, where is inside TEdit

Comment: @pnieradko but it is not declared nor asigned.. (where and how are you assigning it?)

Comment: You might notice that the block of the `i`-indexed `for` loop doesn't make any reference to `i`. That's probably a bug. Also, are you sure you mean `Components` and `ComponentCount`, and not `Controls` and `ControlCount`? In any case, it is probably better to put your edit controls in an array.

Comment: The code in the first comment is fine. I mean, if the edit control is empty, how do you expect to convert an empty string into an integer? I wonder why you don't keep track of the controls in an array.

Answer (score 0):

The code provided does not match the screenshot shown. What is being passed as the `Component` parameter to `zlicz_liczby()`? Is it the Form itself? The ScrollBox? A specified Panel?

Let's just iterate the Panels in the ScrollBox directly.  Try something more like this:

```pascal
function TfrmGenerateExam.zlicz_liczby: Integer;
var
  i, j: integer;
  Panel: TPanel;
begin
  Result := 0;
  for i := 0 to ScrollBox1.ControlCount - 1 do
  begin
    Panel := ScrollBox1.ControlCount[i] as TPanel;
    for j := 0 to Panel.ControlCount - 1 do
    begin
      if Panel.Controls[j] is TEdit then
        Result := Result + StrToIntDef(TEdit(Panel.Controls[j]).Text, 0);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

That being said, as @AndreasRejbrand stated in comments, you should use an array instead.  When you create a new `TPanel` with a `TEdit` on it, put its `TEdit` into a `TList<TEdit>`, for instance.  If you destroy the `TPanel`, remove its `TEdit` from the list.  And then you can simply loop through that list whenever needed, without having to hunt for the `TEdit` controls at all.  For example:

```pascal
private
  Edits: TList<TEdit>;

procedure TfrmGenerateExam.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edits := TList<TEdit>.Create;
end;

procedure TfrmGenerateExam.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edits.Free;
end;

function TfrmGenerateExam.FillScrollBox;
var
  Panel: TPanel;
  Edit: TEdit;
begin
  ...
  Panel := TPanel.Create(Self);
  Panel.Parent := ScrollBox1;
  ...
  Edit := TEdit.Create(Panel);
  Edit.Parent := Panel;
  ...
  Edits.Add(Edit);
  ...
end;

function TfrmGenerateExam.zlicz_liczby: Integer;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  for i := 0 to Edits.Count - 1 do
    Result := Result + StrToInt(Edits[i].Text);
end;
```

Comment: Still its doesnt work.
I think, probably create badly dynamic object.

Comment: @pnieradko Well, without seeing how you are actually constructing the Form elements at runtime, it is very hard to give you a definitive answer.  So I gave you an example.  If it is not working for you, then you need to edit your question to provide more details about your actual setup.

Comment: Can You take a look in this all code and tell me my mistakes, please?
I will be thankful :-)

[link](https://wtools.io/paste-code/b2ow)
I hope I didn't make a lot of mistakes

Comment: @pnieradko again, please EDIT YOUR QUESTION to add more details.  Do not host code on an external site.  Links break over time, and StackOverflow questions are expected to be self-contained.  So please, put the relevant portions directly in your question instead.

Comment: When I create dynamic Edits in empty form, its work, but if I create with Parent Panel, it doesnt work.

Comment: @pnieradko Again, please edit your question to show the actual code, so someone can explain why it is not working for you.